# Possible to predict the polarity of a magnet using only molecular analysis?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, molecules, ferromagnetism

Is it possible to analyze the molecular arrangement of a magnet to predict which end is north? Or is it always a surprise until we see how it behaves near another magnet?

Answer (score 0):

A permanent magnet is possible I think. It's not molecular but crystal structure, which depends on impurities, cooling speed, and of course the presence of external fields. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain#/media/File%3ANdFeB-Domains.jpg

For 3 phase motors it's often not known which way the rotor will turn until it's switched on, but that is just because they may be wound in either direction and they may not be labelled.

Comment: Which side of the magnet in that image would be north? Or if this is not possible to answer, then in which direction would the north-south axis run?